# How to check validity of entity before insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa

The problem I have is about the insertion. When a user has a property invalid like the firstName stops the all process. How can I handle the exception?

```
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
private String firstName;


    adService.findAll().stream().forEach(adUser -> {
        if (!adUser.isLockedOut()) {
            Optional<User> dbUser = userService.getUserByLoginAndEmployeeId(adUser.getLogin(),
                    adUser.getEmployeeId());
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(adUser.getEmployeeId())) {
                if (!dbUser.isPresent()) {
                    userService.saveUser(adUser);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, if it's invalid, why do you insist on saving it?

Comment: I have an interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> and I call save(entity)

Comment: I understand that. The question is, why do you want to handle an error that shouldn't be handled? You actually want to save a user even if the `firstName` is invalid?

Comment: I am sorry... When I insert multiple users if one user has invalid firstname then stoped all the loop. I want to continue with the next user and give me just a log about the problem

Comment: In such case, just make every call to `saveUser` start a separate transaction using `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`. You can then surround the `userService.saveUser(adUser)` line with a try-catch block

Comment: I did as you said but I have the same problem. Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only